# Angular 6 build failed to load resources

Tags: angular, build

I am trying to build my app using the command `ng build --prod` but when I try to load the index.html file in the `dist` folder, I get the following errors:

```
styles.76a1111….css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
runtime.06daa30….js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
polyfills.f6ae3e8….js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
scripts.f11023c….js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.4ee5dbf….js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
styles.76a1111….css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

In the **index.html** file I have the following:

```
<base href="/">
```

**angular.json file**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "digital": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/digital",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "digital:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "digital:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "digital:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "wedigital-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "digital:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "digital:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "digital",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

**Other information:**

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.7
Node: 8.10.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.1.10
```

Files in `dist` folder

```
3rdpartylicenses.txt
assets
favicon.ico
index.html
main.4ee5dbfc414143867b55.js
polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js
runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js
scripts.f11023cbae55e24a4eeb.js
styles.76a1111b5a6844e3fc2b.css
```

Comment: what is the output of `ng build --prod --verbose` ?

Comment: The above command gives the same output and errors

Comment: Which files do you have in the `dist` folder  ? and do you edited the content of `index.html` ?

Comment: The files I have is above in the question ( i have updated it), and no I have not edited the index.html?

Comment: the verbose should have more details..Make sure it have more output as a normal build and look into this and try with the `--progress` flag to show step by step what is going wrong

Comment: Even doing `ng build --prod --verbose` gives the same output folder as above

Comment: Did you try deploying it in a server?

Comment: Yes and i still get those errors of failed to load resources

Answer (score 14):

You need to change `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">`

Comment: Or just remove it, since that's the implicit `base`.

Comment: Thanks mate. This is the right answer and it should be mark as a right with the green tick!!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open `index.html` directly from `dist` folder. You have to use some kind of Reverse Proxy Server.

You can use [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/).

Modify and add the below configuration in your `nginx.conf` file:

```
location /angular {
   alias "C:\\<Your Project Location>\\dist";   
   index index.html index.htm;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

Then you can access your project dist files as:
http://localhost/angular

And your error will also be solved.

Assuming that your `angular.json` file has `baseHref` and `deployUrl` properly defined.
**Example:**

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "<Your project>": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/angular/",
            "deployUrl": "/angular/",
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Below instruction,

1. Router configuration with AppModule

   `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })`
2. Remove base URL from index.html and add dynamically in AppModule

   `import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
   providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],`

Comment: This brings in 10 errors: GET http://localhost:4200/policy/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: did you remove `<base href="/">` from index.html?

Comment: Yes I did do that